# Change the output by using a extending method in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to do something like this in PHP?

```
Image::myMethod(); // returns array
Image::myMethod()->toSring(); // Returns a string built inside the method toString
```

So, in other words, is there a way for PHP to detect if the method is being extended by another method if yes it then returns the `self/this`?

Comment: Nope, but `myMethod` can return an object implementing `ArrayAccess` that also has a `toString` defined upon it. Since `ArrayAccess` acts as a native associative array in most contexts, callers won't usually notice a difference.

Comment: Detecting anything in the caller is always the wrong approach. How about `$a = Image::myMethod(); $a->toString();`? What if `$a` is passed around to someplace else before `->toString()` is called? No, a function returns a defined type dependent solely on its input. Period, end of story.

Comment: @bishop You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The `->toString()` is a custom method that does custom stuff with `implode()`. Anyways, it seems I can't do it with PHP.

Comment: @GuillaumeBoudreau Done. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codifying what I meant in comment, this will give you logically the same behavior, though the implementation details differ:

```
class Artifact extends ArrayObject {
    public function toString(): string {
        // custom stuff, use ArrayObject api to access underlying data
    }
}

class Image {
    public function myMethod(): Artifact {
        // generate your array data, then:
        return new Artifact($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it's impossible. But you can implement pretty similar behaviour by making __toString() magic method and implementing ArrayAccess interface (and Iterator if you want to use it in loops).

Alas, the implementation might be pretty bulky.

```
class MyClass implements Iterator, ArrayAccess 
{
    ...
    public function __toString() { ... }
    public function current ( ) { ... }
    public function key ( )  { ... }
    public function next ( ) { ... }
    public function rewind ( ) { ... }
    public function valid ( ) { ... }
    public function offsetExists ( $offset ) { ... }
    public function offsetGet ( $offset ) { ... }
    public function offsetSet ( $offset , $value ) { ... }
    public function offsetUnset ( $offset ) { ... }
}

function myFunc()
{
    return new MyClass(...);
}

(string)myFunc() // returns string value
myFunc()[0]  // access as array
foreach (myFunc() as $value) // iterate as array
```